# Lyx itemize returning to last number

Tags: lyx, itemize

I would like to have the following output:

1. Text

   (a) Text

   Text
2. Text

That is, after a subitem, I want to return to the last number without creating a new one. Is there any way to do this without ERT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply use `Ctrl-Enter` to break the item text. This is like  insert `\\` in LaTeX.

Lyx MWE:

```
LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Enumerate
Text
\end_layout

\begin_deeper
\begin_layout Enumerate
Text 
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset

Text
\end_layout

\end_deeper
\begin_layout Enumerate
Text
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

[image: MWE]

LaTeX version:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Text

\begin{enumerate}
\item Text \\
\\
Text
\end{enumerate}
\item Text
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**: If you want the text aligned with the item (a), you are looking for a linguist package as  `linguex`, but there are no module for LyX (but using ERT boxes are not very intrusive in this case):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\ex. Text
    \a. Text
\z. Text

\ex. Text 

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE2]

Comment: Fran, thanks, but I would like to have the text aligned in the same way as the text after 1. is. In your answer, we have the text aligned in the same way as the text after (a) is.

Comment: @LuizMMB. See the added example with `linguex`. Lyx cannot manage directly package. The more similar that Lyx understand is the "linguist" module (`congvinton` package) but do nto allow this as far I know.

Answer (score 6):

Insert a "custom item" for the oddly-placed entry

[image]

and leave the entry blank

[image]

This leaves you with:

[image]

Comment: Really is the best solution, no doubt (+1). But it is worth to note that this feature is present in Lyx 2.2, not in previous versions sitll used by many Linux distributions. For example the newborn Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty) still have the Lyx 2.0.5.1.

Comment: @Fran Good point and I agree that it should be noted that it's a feature of LyX 2.1 (not 2.2). Note however that many people use the LyX Ubuntu PPA.

Comment: @scottkosty Yes, 2.1. I forgot that was seening the development version (2.2.0dev) and not the latest stable.

Answer (score 4):

This is supported natively in LyX; there's no need for the tricks in the other answers.

In the following:

1. First item

   (a) Subitem

   More of the first item
2. Second item

Make a separate paragraph for each, including the "more of the first item" one. Set its paragraph style to normal (like if it were not part of any list), and press tab to indent it (like you already did to subitem). It should all now look correct both in LyX and in the PDF output.